# D-pad navigation not going to next focus item

Tags: android, focus

I have a reasonably complex application that has a global header that is visible through various menus: main menu, sub menu and item description etc

One of the views on the top menu has got next focus set to another view as the default navigation flow was not ideal.  However Android appears to be ignoring this and doing nothing! The focus remains on the button.

I added some debug in the key listener and printed the get next focus id vs. the actual id i want to give focus to and these matched!

This is just one example! There are a few other locations in which the next focus options (either by XML or pro grammatically) are simply being ignored.

Has anyone else came across this behaviour before? The fact that the button knows the correct id (and the view is visible etc) to me means it should be getting focus!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!  The issue was that i had another Fragment that was being initialised with an View that had the same id.  The request focus internally is then finding this view id first and and such attempting to focus to that instead of the one i intended.  I need to do some refactoring it seems.